# Appending elements through JavaScript for dynamically generated id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 <li class="list" id='+id+'>
  <a class="anchor" id='+id+' href='#stay' onClick="getValue(this);"       style="text-decoration: none, color:red">hello</a>
```

Now inside JavaScript:

```
  listElem=listElem+'<li class="list" style="height: 18px; display: inline-       block;width:100px;line-height: 20px;padding-right:25px;"><a class="anchor"      id=""+results+"" href="#stay"  style="width:1028px;">"+results+"</a>  </li>';
```

Now I need to append the listElem after li tag. Since id is dynamically     generated.

How could I append it through innerHTML or html()?

How could I pass id here: `$( "" ).html(listElem);` or is here any other method?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option:

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
var li1 = makeLi();
var li2 = makeLi();
var li3 = makeLi();
insert(ul, li2); // insert #my-uid-2
insert(ul, li1); // insert #my-uid-1
insert(ul, li3); // insert #my-uid-3

function uid () {
  var i = 1;
  return (this.uid = function () {
    return 'my-uid-' + (i++);
  })();
};

function makeLi () {
  var re = /\+id\+/g;
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  var li = '<li id="+id+">#+id+</li>';
  return (this.makeLi = function () {
    ul.innerHTML = li.replace(re, uid());
    return ul.firstChild;
  })();
}

function insert (ul, li) {
  var child;
  var i = 0;
  var re = /^.*?(\d+)$/;
  var n = +li.id.replace(re, '$1');
  var children = ul.childNodes;
  while (
    (child = children[i]) && 
    n > +child.id.replace(re, '$1')
  ) i++;
  if (child) ul.insertBefore(li, child)
  else ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

```css
#my-uid-1 {
  background: yellow;
}
#my-uid-2 {
  background: orange;
}
#my-uid-3 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for jQuery's [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) and [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) methods.

If, say you have your HTML code in a a variable `listItem`, you can convert it to jQuery object, use `prop()` to set id and then `insertAfter()` to place it the last `<li>` element with a `class="list"`:

```
var listElem = jQuery('<li class="list" style="height: 18px; display: inline-block;width:100px;line-height: 20px;padding-right:25px;"><a class="anchor" id=""+results+"" href="#stay"  style="width:1028px;">"+results+"</a></li>');
listElem.prop('id', id).insertAfter('li.list:last');
```

Comment: <li class="list"..> is also dynamically generated since it depends on the data from database so all the list tag have same class="list" .

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this on click event

```
<li class="list" id='+id+' onclick='getvalue(this)'>
  <a class="anchor" id='+id+' href='#stay' onClick="getValue(this);"       style="text-decoration: none, color:red">hello</a>
```

jQuery code:

```
function getvalue(elem){
 var listElem='<li class="list" style="height: 18px; display: inline-       block;width:100px;line-height: 20px;padding-right:25px;"><a class="anchor"      id=""+results+"" href="#stay"  style="width:1028px;">"+results+"</a>  </li>';
 var id=$(elem).attr('id');
 $('#'+id).html(listElem);//your code
}
```

Comment: not working using $('#'+id).html(listElem) also not showing error

Comment: may be listElem was undefined earlier .. try newly edited answer

Comment: i am getting the id value but still output not showing the appended value

Comment: let me try this in fiddle.. wait 10 mins

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then jQuery provides the `before` method of jQuery objects. To append `listElem` before the `li` element, you could call

```
$('#+id+').before(listElem);
```

Comment: @kumar91: I'm sorry, I must not have understood your question then. Perhaps if you could clarify?

Comment: suppose <li id='+id+'></li> is there where id is dynamically generated and now i want the value of ul tag as hello world so through javascript we can do this like document.getElementById("id").innerHTML="hello world".But since id is dynamically generated i am using var id=$(elem).attr("id"); and then using $("#"+id).html("hello world"); but its not working.